# Android - Set Height to TextView Dynamically

Tags: android

I have some critical issue related to height of TextView. I want to set the height of the TextView based on the content which is set at runtime. Here is my xml code:-

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/tv" 
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>`
```

Here is the java code to set the height of the TextView:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.invalidate();
int height_in_pixels = tv.getLineCount() * tv.getLineHeight();
tv.setHeight(height_in_pixels);
```

But the problem is that it displays only 1 line, and not the rest of the lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java Code:

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

```
tv.invalidate();

int height_in_pixels = tv.getLineCount() * tv.getLineHeight();

tv.setHeight(height_in_pixels);
```

**these lines are unwanted in java code**. In xml itself you have mentioned the `layout_height="wrap_content"`. then why you are setting again the height of the `TextView`. and Make sure that `android:singleLine="false"` in the `<textview>`.if you not set anything,  its default value is false.

Comment: @RATTLESNAKE: Then Problem is in your input :)). can you post your screenshot on your question?

Answer (score 1):

> But the problem is; it displays only
>   1 line, and not the rest of the lines.

I think the best solution is to define your textview inside the "ScrollView".

For example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView 
            android:text="@+id/TextView01" 
            android:id="@+id/TextView01" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```